# Android animate move, stop and move other widget

Tags: android, android-animation

in this simple move animate i want to after finishing move widget, stop animate and move other widget, both of all animates must be stop after finish and dont recursive previous state

move up xml:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="-100%" />

</set>
```

move down xml:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fromYDelta="-100%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />

</set>
```

my code:

```
public class ActivitySmsReceiveSlave extends Activity implements AnimationListener {
    private Animation                         animMoveUp;
    private Animation                         animMoveDown;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sms_receive_slave_view);
        G.currentActivity = this;
        animMoveUp = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.animation_move_up);
        animMoveUp.setAnimationListener(this);

        animMoveDown = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.animation_move_up);

        detaileLinearLayout.startAnimation(animMoveUp);
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (animation == animMoveUp) {
            testLinear.startAnimation(animMoveDown);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
    }
}
```

in my xml animations and code, after finish move up or move down animate, widget recursive start state and `testLinear` widget dont start to animation

Answer (score -1):

```
package com.example.testmove;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.Animation.AnimationListener;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements AnimationListener {
    private Animation   animMoveUp;
    private Animation  animMoveDown;
    ImageView img;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        animMoveUp = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.movedown);
        animMoveUp.setAnimationListener(this);

        animMoveDown = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.moveup);
        animMoveDown.setAnimationListener(this);
        img.startAnimation(animMoveUp);

    }
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (animation == animMoveUp) {
            img.startAnimation(animMoveDown);
        }
        if(animation == animMoveDown){
            img.setAnimation(null);        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
    }
}
```

Comment: why you downcast my answer it is working i am running then post this answer to you if you have any trouble then ask and if you want to full support then you must send me layout of this program i trying to do exactly what you want............

Comment: my problem was in xml animation file and i can fix it